# KQL where does $table and MDTables come from?

Tags: kql

I have a couple of questions about where these "variables" come from in KQL --

1. $table

> ```
> search *
> | distinct $table
> | sort by $table asc nulls last
> ```

What is a $table?  Where does this variable come from?

2. MDTable in figuring eps and GBs per second

> ```
> let bytes_ = 500;
> union withsource=MDTables*
> | where Timestamp > startofday(ago(1d))
> | summarize count() by bin(Timestamp, 1m), MDTables
> | extend EPS = count_ /60
> |summarize avg(EPS), estimatedGBytes = (avg(EPS) * bytes_ ) / (1024*1024*1024) by MDTables
> | sort by toint(estimatedGBytes) desc
> ```

Where does the MDTables variable come from in the above events per second, gb's per second?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @jreacher403, I guess the $table is used as an alias for the column that definrs the table name in query result. and its not a variable.

Comment: [The output will always include a column called $table of type string whose value is the table name from which each record was retrieved (or some system-generated name if the source isn't a table but a composite expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said earlier **$table** is a placeholder for a field in your log data. The search * retrieves all records, right so distinct $table gets unique values from the $table field. this is ,mostly used in Azure Monitor Logs to represents a log entry.

and secondly the **MDTables** is an alias used for a field in your log datawhich represents different tables with names starting with "MDTables.

i guess the query calculates **events per second and gigabytes per second for each table,** grouping the results by the MDTables field. **MDTables** is used for readability in this context according to my analysis and the actual field name might vary based on your specific log schema.